# Is there a difference between array and number datatype in Javascript prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I am nerd in javascript prototypal inheritance.I can understand what happening in below code

```
function Hamster() {  }
Hamster.prototype = {
  food: [],
  found: function(something) {
    this.food.push(something)
  }
}

// Create two speedy and lazy hamsters, then feed the first one
speedy = new Hamster()
lazy = new Hamster()

speedy.found("apple")
speedy.found("orange")

alert(speedy.food.length) // 2
```

And below line is also alert `2` b'coz both object is sharing `food` array from `Hamster`'s prototype

```
alert(lazy.food.length) // 2
```

But if i change datatype of array into number , `food`  key is not sharing between both instances

```
function Hamster() {  }
Hamster.prototype = {
  food: 0,
  found: function(something) {
    this.food = something
  }
}

// Create two speedy and lazy hamsters, then feed the first one
speedy = new Hamster()
lazy = new Hamster()

speedy.found(123)


alert(speedy.food) // 123
```

But the below line alerts `0` , Could you please tell me why this doesn't alert `123`

```
alert(lazy.food) // 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each instance of `Hamster` has its own `food` property. But in the first version, they all point to the same array, which you're modifying in place with `push`. In the second version, they point to integers, which can't be modified in place; the `found` function reassigns that instance's property, which has no effect on other instances.

To give each instance its own `food` array property, you need to use a constructor that assigns it.

You can see similar behavior with the following, which just uses ordinary variables rather than objects and inheritance.

```
arr1 = [];
arr2 = arr1;
arr1.push(1);
console.log(arr2); // prints [1]

int1 = 0;
int2 = int1;
int1 = 1;
console.log(int2); // prints 0
```

Assigning operator '=' removes the pointer from variable

```
arr1 = [];
arr2 = arr1;
arr2 = ['Appple'];
console.log(arr1); // prints []
```

Comment: I just modified the `found` function `found: function(something) {
        this.food += something
      }`
Instead of re assigning it , still i am getting `0` for `lazy`'s instance

Comment: That doesn't make a difference, `this.food +=` is just shorthand for `this.food = this.food + `. Numbers can't be modified in place, they aren't composite objects like arrays and objects.

Comment: The thing to understand is that in the first case *both objects still have their own value for `food`*; it's just that their value in each case is a reference to the same object in memory.

Comment: Right, @Vimalraj.S because each object gets its own `food` in both the first case *and* the second case.

Comment: You can't make two properties point to the same number, numbers are not independent objects.

Comment: `array.push` does **not** create a new reference. That's the whole point. Both objects have a `food` property that references the *same* array in memory, so when you push an element onto that array (through *either* reference), you're still always updating the same array.

Comment: I've added a small demo to the answer that shows the behavior in terms of simple variables; prototype inheritance just obscures what's actually going on.

Comment: Thanks , Yours edit  and lwburk's answers gives me the solution

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, attributes lookups follow Prototype chain, but not attribute assignments.

So, when you say

```
this.food = something;
```

`food` attribute is created on the object. So, it overrides the `food` from the `prototype`. But when you access `lazy`, since it is attribute lookup, first the current object is searched and then the prototype, where it is defined and assigned value 0. That is why it alerts 0.

Comment: But it's not shared in the second version, that's his question.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to understand is that in the first case both objects still have their own value for `food`; it's just that their value in each case is a reference to the same object in memory, so pushing an item into the array referenced by that property changes the same array.

@Barmar's answer, which I upvoted, already said all that, but here's another example that should help demonstrate this:

```
function Hamster() {}

Hamster.prototype = {
    food: [],
    found: function(something) {
        this.food = something;
    }
}

// Create two speedy and lazy hamsters, then feed the first one
speedy = new Hamster()
lazy = new Hamster()

speedy.found(["apple"])
speedy.found(["orange"])

alert(speedy.food) // orange
alert(lazy.food) // <empty>
```

In this case, each `food` property gets a reference to a *different* array, so it's clear that each property is independent.

The key thing to take away:

The **value of a variable that holds an object is a *reference*** to that object. The **value of a variable that holds a primitive (like a number) is the value of the primitive** itself.

Comment: @Vimal raj.S Your suggested edit completely undid the point of my example, which is to show that each new object gets its own `food` property in every case. I don't know how else this can be explained so that you'll get it. It may just take some time (or maybe someone else will answer in a way different from me and @Barmar that makes sense to you). Good luck!

Comment: +1 because you made the effort to try to explain that.

Comment: @lwburk, No, In your example `speedy.found(["apple"])` doesn't make any sense here , because we are assigning the value in found function , so it will work same as `speedy.found("apple")` which uses a instance `food` variable.

However your answer gives a better idea , and now my doubt is How Array.Push works with reference while assigning operator `=` cannot ?

Comment: I think you've missed the entire point of my example. I'm sorry that it didn't help.